# Missing Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell in MS Virtual Machine Manager 2012 installation

Tags: windows, virtual-machine-manager

Im installing VMM 2012 on a virtual machine. The installer throws the error

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell, Version=6.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Issue is that this assembly seems very hard to find. Any advice what I possibly could have missed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized to one unknown user error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by restarting the computer and running the installation again!